# Long term application level pessimistic locking in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a resource (e.g. a "document") stored in a SQL Server table.

Users need to be able to obtain an application level lock (not a database lock) on this resource, and hold that lock potentially forever.

I've come up with a strategy to handle this, but I'm not sure if it's correct and would appreciate some advice.

In this particular application the number of users and resources will be very low, so there won't be much contention. But it would still be nice to know the most appropriate or "proper" way to handle this situation.

The table to record the locks is simple enough:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ResourceLock]
(
    [Id]            [int]           NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ResourceId]    [int]           NOT NULL,
    [UserId]        [int]           NOT NULL,
    [Created]       [datetime2](7)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderLock] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )
)
```

And then the query to attempt to take out a lock on the resource:

```
--Incoming Parameters 
DECLARE @ResourceId INT;
DECLARE @UserId INT;

--Query Variables
DECLARE @LockId INT;
DECLARE @InsertedIds TABLE (Id INT);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT  @LockId = [ResourceLock].[Id]
--TABLOCKX the table so it can't be accessed until after the transaction is complete.
FROM    [ResourceLock] WITH (TABLOCKX)
WHERE   [ResourceLock].[ResourceId] = @ResourceId;

IF @LockId IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [ResourceLock]
    (
        [ResourceId],
        [UserId],
        [Created]
    )
    OUTPUT inserted.Id INTO @InsertedIds(Id)
    VALUES
    (
        @ResourceId,
        @UserId,
        GETUTCDATE()
    );

    SELECT  @LockID = Id
    FROM    @InsertedIds;
END

SELECT  [ResourceLock].*
FROM    [ResourceLock]
WHERE   [ResourceLock].[Id] = @LockId;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

First it checks to see if a lock on the resource already exists. As part of that check the `SELECT` specifies `TABLOCKX` preventing another instance of this query, or any other query from accessing this table until this transaction is complete.

If there is no existing lock it then creates a new lock on the resource for the user.

Finally it returns the existing, or newly created lock.

The application will then simply compare the requesting user against the user holding the lock and will let the user know if they have obtained the lock, or if the lock is held by someone else.

When other queries attempt to write to the resource they'll use a check like this:

```
--Incoming Parameters 
DECLARE @ResourceId INT;
DECLARE @UserId INT;

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT  [ResourceLock].*
    FROM    [ResourceLock]
    WHERE   [ResourceLock].[ResourceId] = @ResourceId
    AND     [ResourceLock].[UserId] = @UserId
)
BEGIN
    --UPDATE the resource
END
```

My main concern is around the use of `TABLOCKX`, as it's very heavy handed. This feels like something that might be achievable with a different approach which would be more efficient, but I haven't been able to find anything like that when searching.

I think my searching attempts have been hampered by the fact I have two types of locking going on here. Locking in SQL Server, and application resource locking.

Comment: Having a table with a single cell can do the job for you in my sight. Just check if it is null or not, if null this means no other is currently querying. This eliminates the need for `TABLOCKX`. You can also use transactions with that table cell to handle concurrent access

Comment: If a resource can only ever be locked by a single user, it seems more obvious to have a `UNIQUE` index on it, which would act as a backstop for any error in logic. (Catching the constraint violation to see if the lock is there is also possible, but that's a little clumsy.) I agree with the other comment that a table lock seems unnecessarily heavy handed. A `SERIALIZABLE` transaction will already take care of locking the appropriate rows, even if those rows do not yet exist. There's no need to use a global lock.

Comment: You should have stated up front that table is an application level lock.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It was my post that said it's heavy handed ;) That's mainly why I posted asking for advice. Thanks for the tip, would you mind creating an answer for it?

Comment: My experience has always tended to be that ~2 weeks after the users ask for some locking system, they start asking for ways to bypass the locks ("the user left for lunch/the day/a new job" being the usual justification). Before long, your locks don't really mean much and you have to handle conflict *anyway*. Try to persuade your users that this is virtually inevitable and so you may as well start looking for conflict resolution rules rather than trying to implement heavy handed locks.

Comment: @AndyJ: Oh no, not me. I have some experience with custom locking systems: just enough to know that getting it right is hard and always requires extensive testing to confirm that you did get it right, while getting it wrong with a tricky concurrent scenario that you missed is much easier. In that sense, starting off with a table lock is *not wrong*. :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point. Bypassing the locks is already part of the system, there will be admin users that can do that. We have also proposed a system using optimistic locking, but the client doesn't want to pay the extra for that to be implemented. If they change their minds in 2 weeks, then we'll be more than happy to do more work for them!

Comment: @JeroenMostert Fair enough! Thanks again.

Comment: @paparazzo Thanks for suggesting that improvement. I've updated the title and intro text.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to go is to view the @ResourceId itself as an identifier of a virtual resource to "lock", so that you can have free reign to take care of whatever DML is needed to record this long-term pessimistic lock in your operational tables. However, it's best in this kind of situation to avoid the usual blocking/locking/etc., as those are not very scalable, and you may introduce deadlocking and other challenges.

You could use SQL Server's built-in Lock Manager, via sp_getapplock, to temporarily lock a "resource", so that you can work on that resource in isolation for a period of time. However, it is best not to actually physically lock data rows in tables if you can help it. As you will see below, sp_getapplock can be used as a "gate", and if you can "lock" the virtual resource, now you are "in", and you can operate *WITHIN THE SCOPE OF THAT RESOURCE*, without actually locking/blocking/holding on base tables. Locks on base tables will not only hold the row locks, but they will hold object and schema locks, too. Not good.

Using sp_getapplock will allow you to have custom mutexes, if you will, and not actually be locking user tables, especially with blunt instruments like TABLOCKX. Of course, this strategy relies upon you, and your app, behaving and using sp_getapplock and sp_releaseapplock via some kind of custom lock semantics, but you already want to do this anyway.

```
--Construct unique name for 'resource'      
DECLARE @resourceName nvarchar(255) = 'RESOURCEID:' + CAST(@ResourceId AS NVARCHAR(10))

DECLARE @retVal INT = 0;

EXEC @retVal = sp_getapplock
  @Resource = @resourceName
  ,  @LockMode = 'Exclusive'
  ,  @LockOwner = 'Session' 
  ,  @LockTimeout = 10000;

IF @retVal <= 1
  BEGIN
    /*
     Do whatever you want here, including logging into your "long-term" lock 
     table, etc. You now have a pessimistic short-term lock on @resourceName, 
     and you can act with impunity in any related tables while you hold this 
    "lock", but you are not actually locking the database resources such as 
    your resource locking/logging table.
    */
  END

EXEC sp_releaseapplock
  @Resource = @resourceName
  @LockOwner = 'Session';
```

Also, should your app crash, disconnect, or fail to call `sp_releaseapplock`, this session-level lock is automatically released by the Lock Manager when your session is terminated.

Comment: I haven't heard of `sp_getapplock ` before, so that gives me something to read up on. Thanks!

Comment: It's terrific. I use it all the time.

Comment: I've had a read through the documentation and that's a very useful tool for the tool belt. Unfortunately it doesn't fit my specific situation due to it being session bound. The lock needs to be persistent between sessions both because the client is a web app, so the client doesn't actually hold a session open, and because it needs to survive database server resets. Hopefully others will find your answer useful, and I've certainly found it very interesting!

Comment: @AndyJ I think you missed a piece of the point. You lock the mutex, then you can READ/WRITE to your actual long-term management tables. The mutex just prevents all kinds of physical locking issues while you are doing that. So, sp_getapplock; --read long-term lock table --take whatever actions you want; sp_releaseapplock;. Nowhere in my solution does it say to use the session lock as the long term solution. It's a tool to enable you to treat an entire 'process' or 'set of data' as a virtual resource to be locked for an arbitrary period of time. This is extremely useful for orchestration.

Comment: @AndyJ re-visit the comment block between BEGIN/END. You could do lots of things in that block, such as checking if the "lock" row exists in your target table, run a process, stage up some data, whatever, for however long, without actually holding physical locks or latches against the base tables while you are doing it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at. It allows me to create a mutex against the Resource row, even though that's not part of the query. So I don't need to lock the entire Lock table. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @AndyJ you got it!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your solution would work without a `HOLDLOCK`.  Have you tested it?

I think up can do it with an `UPLOCK, HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK`

You can shorten it and you don't need an explicit transaction

```
INSERT INTO [ResourceLock] ([ResourceId], [UserId], [Created]) 
select @ResourceId, @UserId, GETUTCDATE()  
where not exists ( select 1 
                     from [ResourceLock] with (UPLOCK, HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
                    where [ResourceId] = @ResourceId
                  )
```